# How to query for the messages between the exact recipients?

Tags: laravel

Is there a similar "whereIn" for "whereInBetween" in Laravel 7+? I have a basic chat app:

### Message model

> id, content, userId, threadId

`threadId` is filled when a user replies to a message. Think "parentId".

```php
public function sentBy(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId');
}

public function recipients(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(MessageRecipient::class);
}
```

### Recipients model

> id, userId, messageId

```php
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId');
}

public function message(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Message::class, 'messageId');
}
```

I could then say:

```php
User::first()->messages;

Message::first()->sentBy;
```

With this setup, the `recipients` model could easily be called "group". When a user creates a message, a `recipients` relationship is created for the current user along with other users regardless if the message was sent to the one who created the message. Common? Ok. My issue is this, I need to return all conversation between us three userIds: `[1,2,3]`:

```php
$messageId = 1;
// Message with id of 1 will not have a threadId, only its replies.

$userIds = [1,2,3];

foreach($userIds as $id) {

  Recipient::create(['messageId' => $messageId, 'userId' => $id]);

}
```

We have a "group chat theme" going on here. If I need to query for message with us three users (above userIds), I'd do:

```php
return Message::whereHas('recipients', function(Builder $q) use ($userIds) {
    return $q->whereIn('userId', $userIds);
})
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Perfect. Exactly what I need. Now, let's create another message:

```php
$messageId = 2;
$userIds = [1,2];
$queryUserIds = [2,3];

foreach($userIds as id) {

  Recipient::create(['messageId' => $messageId, 'userId' => $id]);

}

// With this query, I'd expect to see message between the two queryUserIds **only**,
// Expected results should be an empty array because we have no message between userId 2 and 3 only. We have messages between all three: 1,2,3.
return Message::whereHas('recipients', function(Builder $q) use ($queryUserIds) {
    return $q->whereIn('userId', $queryUserIds);
})
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->get();
```

How can I query messages between a set of userIds. Not sure I'm expressing myself correctly. All Im saying is, for users 1, 2 and 3, give me conversations with only those three users and nothing else because only those three are in the same conversation.

I got this idea from Facebook's messenger. I don't know how they do it but I'm "borrowing" a functionality; when you create a new message, it seems to retrieve the last/latest conversations between same "recipients". I know there are more complexities that go on but I wanted to do something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found it. Correct me if I'm wrong. To recap, when a message is created, it creates an array of recipients with a message.threadId of null. When anyone replies to that message, you'll now have a `message.threadId` of 1. When I want messages between all three users: `1,2,3`, I'd query:

```php
$userIds = [1,2,3];
// Probably could use sql's sum but... 
$sumIds = array_sum($userIds);

$messages = Message::whereHas('recipients', function(Builder $q) use ($sumIds) {
    // SUM is the key part.
    return $q->havingRaw('SUM(recipients.userId) ='. $sumIds);
})->get();
```

This works 99% but I want the "replies", messages with `threadId` not null; I need the replies:

```php
$message = Message::whereHas('recipients', function(Builder $q) use ($sumIds) {
    return $q->havingRaw('SUM(recipients.userId) ='. $sumIds);
})
// I literally need the first in the array. I'd expect the array should contain one object and never more than one
->first();

if (!$message) {
    return [];
}

// Another query to get all (conversations). You'll now see the picture:
return Message::where(function($q) use ($message) {
    $q->orWhere('id', $message->messgeId);
    // This gives me the "replies"
    $q->orWhere('threadId', $message->messgeId);
})->get();
```

This works for now. If anyone could refactor, I'll gladly accept your answer with an upvote.

Thanks!